# A more elegant way to get current year-month to insert in a 'where' clause

Tags: mysql

The table I'm querying from has this DateTime column.

| created_time |
| --- |
| 2022-03-19T15:21:52+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T13:10:22+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T13:09:52+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T13:02:47+08:00 |
| 2022-03-20T20:51:03+08:00 |

```
select extract(year_month from curtime())
```

Using extract (as above) doesn't work as it will get me: 202203.

```
SELECT created_time
FROM `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
where select extract(year_month from curtime())
```

Therefore the query above will not give me any result as my 'where' clause needs to specifically ask for '2022-03%' and not 202203.

```
SELECT created_time
FROM `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
where date_format(p.created_time, '%Y')=(select extract(year from curtime()))
and date_format(p.created_time, '%m')=(select extract(month from curtime()))
```

Therefore I am currently using the query above to obtain Year='2022' **AND** Month='03' which I feel doesn't look that nice and might cause me future problems.

I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to get the current 'Year-Month' (eg.'2022-03%') to use in my 'where' clause.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *The table I'm querying from has this DateTime column.* This is not datetime format which is produced by MySQL. Check your DBMS carefully.

Comment: Please edit your question to include `SHOW CREATE TABLE freemark-prod-zohocrm.patients`, so we can see the actual data-type of the column, guessing `VARCHAR` by what is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `LIKE` Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a10e27b3c51e41dd4642ed4353ddbdf)

Since the query is a simple `YYYY-MM` prefixed lookup, use `LIKE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%%')` as `2022-03-%`. Functioning the same for either `DATETIME` or `VARCHAR` column data-types, and is by-far **the fastest solution regardless of indexing**.

```
SELECT p.created_time
FROM `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
WHERE p.created_time LIKE DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%%');
```

---

### Compare `YEAR_MONTH` Criteria [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e1f6f92fb40b28b44209d59f5cbcc96e)

To fix the issue with the original query not returning results, match the criteria column and value functions. However, as a function is called on the column value *a full-table scan will be performed*.

```
SELECT p.created_time
FROM `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM p.created_time) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW());
```

To prevent a full-table scan avoid altering column values in the criteria using `DATE_FORMAT(created_time)`, `EXTRACT(... FROM created_time)` or other functions, which will cause MySQL to check all rows in the table to determine if the condition matches.

**MySQL 5.5 and earlier [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=b721e250a99551c0ab5d18bfd7adcc73)**

Note: In MySQL 5.5 and earlier, `extract(year_month from curtime())` or for any date specific [Temporal Intervals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals) will return `NULL` because `curtime()` returns the `TIME` portion as `HH:MM:SS`.
The behavior appears to have changed in MySQL 5.6 and later, where `EXTRACT()` will apply to the current date when the date argument is supplied as a `TIME` data-type and failing when supplied as a time string literal.
However, an undesirable value will be returned when using a date + time interval such as `DAY_MINUTE` and the date portion of the value is omitted.

```
SELECT 
curtime(), /* 19:07:40 */
extract(year_month from curtime()), /* NULL */
extract(day_minute from curtime()); /* 1907 */
```

To resolve the issue always use `NOW()`, otherwise in MySQL 5.5 and earlier `curtime()` should be replaced with `CURDATE()` or `NOW()` depending on the interval being used.

---

### `DATE` Interpreted Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7daf007d7e5f2f29c1eadb6063f41b35)

As `DATE_FORMAT()` returns a string literal, to prevent string comparison issues in MySQL such as `'10' > '2' = false`, enforce a `DATE` or `DATETIME` context.

When using `DATE` or `DATETIME` interpreted values (*see explanation below*) to retrieve the rows for an entire month, the following criteria values can be used to force the condition to process in the context of a `DATE` data-type

- `DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-01'))` to get the first day of the current month as a `DATE` data-type
- `LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` to get the the first day of the next month as a `DATE` data-type.

```
SELECT p.created_time
FROM `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
WHERE p.created_time >= DATE(DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01'))
AND p.created_time < LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

- `LAST_DAY(NOW())` will return the date as `2022-03-31`
- `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` will increment the date by one day to `2022-04-01`

**MySQL 5.6+ Results**

```
CREATE TABLE patients_varchar (
  `id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `created_time` VARCHAR(25),
  INDEX(`created_time`)
);

INSERT INTO patients_varchar
  (`id`, `created_time`)
VALUES
  ('1', '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00'), /* Added to verify range */
  ('2', '2022-03-19T15:21:52+08:00'),
  ('3', '2022-03-19T13:10:22+08:00'),
  ('4', '2022-03-19T13:09:52+08:00'),
  ('5', '2022-03-19T13:02:47+08:00'),
  ('6', '2022-03-20T20:51:03+08:00'),
  ('7', '2022-03-31T20:51:03+08:00'),
  ('8', '2022-04-20T20:51:03+08:00'); /* Added to verify range */
```

| created_time |
| --- |
| 2022-03-19T13:02:47+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T13:09:52+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T13:10:22+08:00 |
| 2022-03-19T15:21:52+08:00 |
| 2022-03-20T20:51:03+08:00 |
| 2022-03-31T20:51:03+08:00 |

---

### `VARCHAR` and Date Time Literals Explanation

When the column data-type is `VARCHAR` using a valid date time string literal format such as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+08:00`, MySQL will automatically interpret the column value format of `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS+MM:HH` as a `DATETIME` data-type appropriately when provided a criteria value in the `DATE` or `DATETIME` data-type context.
Please see the [String and Numeric Literals in Date and Time Context](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html#date-and-time-string-numeric-literals) for more details.

---

### `DATETIME` context and time zone offsets

For MySQL 5.6+ to specify the inclusion of a time value, use `TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'))` to force a `DATETIME` context as opposed to using `DATE()`.

For MySQL 5.5 and earlier [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f3419fb39e81715ee51b997678d03113), when specifying a `DATETIME` context, the time zone offset in the column value is not parsed correctly and produces a different result. Using a string context of `DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()), '%Y-%m-%dT23:59:59')` resolves the issue but **may produce unexpected results**, due to the string context comparison eg: `'10' > '2' = false`.
Note: the `T` is required for MySQL to parse the `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` formatted column value correctly.

For [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b1cffef9ac87e52fc55e6339f2d5b1e1) the following conditions will all return `true` due to the `DATETIME` context. While MySQL 8.0+ will process the time zone offset when it is included in the string.

```
SELECT 
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' = TIMESTAMP('2022-02-19T15:21:52'),
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' < TIMESTAMP('2022-02-20T15:21:52'),
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' > TIMESTAMP('2022-02-18T15:21:52'),
  '2022-02-19T00:00:00+08:00' = TIMESTAMP('2022-02-19'),
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' < TIMESTAMP('2022-02-20'),
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' > TIMESTAMP('2022-02-18');
```

As opposed to the following conditions comparing strings that all return **unexpected results**.

```
SELECT 
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' = '2022-02-19T15:21:52', # false
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' <= '2022-02-19T15:21:52', # false
  '2022-02-19T15:21:52+08:00' > '2022-02-19T15:21:52'; # true
```

Answer (score 0):

querying based on function calls such as extract(), or others datepart(), etc. are not [Sargeable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

What you would be better doing is something like

```
where
       created_time >= '2022-03-01'
   AND created_time < '2022-04-01'
```

This way, it gets the entire month in question including time portion up to 2022-03-31 @ 11:59:59pm.

Now, to compare automatically against whatever the current date IS, you can do with MySQL Variables to compute the first of the month and beginning of next month for your from/to range.

```
select 
      ...
   from
      ( select @FirstOfMonth := DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'),
               @FirstOfNextMonth := date_add( @FirstOfMonth, interval 1 month )) sqlvars,
      `freemark-prod-zohocrm`.patients p
   where
           p.created_time >= @FirstOfMonth
       AND p.created_time < @FirstOfNextMonth
```

Comment: or `WHERE p.created_time between str_to_date(concat(extract(year_month from  curdate()),"01"),"%Y%m%d") and last_day(curdate());`

Comment: Ok, I like that... , but what if the filtering is based on some other date basis.  Similar context, but may be coming from other source than just curdate()

Comment: this is a horrible solution, as you would go every row and get the first and last date of the month. and the you cmpare it

Comment: @nbk, no.  The SQLVars pre-calculate the FirstOfMonth and FIrstOfNextMonth. then that is compared to the patients table in the WHERE clause filtering on just that date range

Comment: Added a missing `)`....

Comment: you have two comparisons instead of one, which costs time as i said bad solution+

Comment: The query produces [warnings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-warnings.html), ("Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.")

Comment: @Luuk, thanks for the input,  I am mostly SQL-Server, but know OF and just touch some on MySQL

Comment: @DRapp `month( curdate())` will produce a `3` as opposed to the expected `03` resulting in `2022-3-01` and won't match on `2022-03-01`. While `DATE_ADD` fixes it for the `@firstOfNextMonth`, I recommend using `DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')` instead to produce the desired results. [Here's an Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1f85d1e16e22003633d763967222f918)